# Change column order, row-by-row, alphabetically based on the contents of certain columns?

Tags: r

I have a data frame that gets loaded from Google Sheets. In it's most simple form it looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("col1" = c("usr1", "usr2"),
       "col2a" = c("B", "C"),
       "col2b" = c(30, 20),
       "col3a" = c("A", "B"),
       "col3b" = c(50, 50),
       "col4a" = c("C", "A"),
       "col4b" = c(20, 30))
```

where there is a column for a user, and then groups of columns (e.g. column 2a and column 2b) that are character and numeric, respectively.

What I would like to do is, on a row-by-row basis, change the order of groups of columns alphabetically (i.e. based on col2a, col3a, col4a). It is important that the correct numerical values (i.e. columns col2b, col3b, col4b) are moved along with the "a" columns. Thus, the end result should be something like:

```
data.frame("col1" = c("usr1", "usr2"),
           "col2a" = c("A", "A"),
           "col2b" = c(50, 30),
           "col3a" = c("B", "B"),
           "col3b" = c(30, 50),
           "col4a" = c("C", "C"),
           "col4b" = c(20, 20))
```

I don't know if working in a data frame is even the best way to do this, but since I need to send the data frame back to Google Sheets, it seems to be the best option.

Thank you very much for any help you can offer in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tidyverse approach:

```
df %>% 
  rename_with(.cols = c(-1), .fn = \(x) {  
    paste0(str_sub(x,1,-2), "_", str_sub(x,-1,-1))
  }) %>%
  pivot_longer(-col1,
               names_to = c("Var", ".value"),
               names_sep = "_") %>%
  arrange(col1, a)
```

This gives you the sorted dataset:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
  col1  Var   a         b
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 usr1  col3  A        50
2 usr1  col2  B        30
3 usr1  col4  C        20
4 usr2  col4  A        30
5 usr2  col3  B        50
6 usr2  col2  C        20
```

you can get back to the original using `pivot_wider()` after any further manipulations you need.

Answer (score 0):

There was a little more tricky things I had to do to get things how I needed, but the bulk of the work comes from @Paul's answer. Maybe I didn't ask the question explicitly enough to describe what I needed.

If I follow @Paul's answer I get really close, in that column `a` and column `b` are correct. However, I need `col1` and the `Var` column to maintain their order. A kind of hacky way around this was to separate temporarily into two data frames, order them, and then use `cbind` to combine again.

```
library(tidyr) # Needed for Paul's solution
library(stringr)

temp_df <- select(df, c("a", "b")) # create a temporary data frame holding the sorted values
df <- select(df, -c("a", "b")) # remove the 'a' and 'b' columns

# Order 'df'
df <- with(df, df[order(col1, Var),]) 
df <- cbind(df, temp_df) # recombine the two data frames

# Turn back into wide format
df <- df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Var, names_glue = "{Var}_{.value}",
                         values_from = c(a, b))
```

Thank you for the help finding this solution.